# Add Slide to search in top of the screen?

Tags: android

I want to add Slide to search in top of the screen. I mean when the user slide/swipes an image placed on top of the screen it should direct the user to another screen but when the user slides a little bit it should go back to its own position.

//Code

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;


gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
            gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            };

            ((Button) mainHomeView.findViewById(R.id.btn_home_small_start)).setOnClickListener(HomeActivity_1.this); 
            ((Button) mainHomeView.findViewById(R.id.btn_home_small_start)).setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);


class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity_1.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                        public void run() {
                            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_home_small_start)).animate().translationX(100.0f);
                        }
                    });
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity_1.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you have tried to post the code.....

Comment: I have added the code can you please check once ?